# Copy tasks in build.gradle will not place compile dependencies in one directory and testCompile dependencies in another

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I'm new to Gradle.

When I run the *build*, instead of copying specific dependencies to specific directories, the build adds both *compile* and *testCompile* dependencies to **src/test/resources**.

I would like to be able to copy only *test* *compile* dependencies to **src/test/resources** and all other dependencies to **main/src/resources**.

Thank you

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'


String spring_version = "3.1.2.RELEASE@jar" ; 
String spring_sec_version = "3.1.2.RELEASE@jar" ; 
String hibernate_version = "4.1.7.Final@jar" ; 

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

//  "org.springframework:spring-oxm:"+spring_version,

List spring = [
    "org.springframework:spring-context:"+spring_version,
    "org.springframework:spring-beans:"+spring_version,
    "org.springframework:spring-core:"+spring_version,
    "org.springframework:spring-aop:"+spring_version,
    "org.springframework:spring-expression:"+spring_version,
    "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:"+spring_version,
    "org.springframework:spring-tx:"+spring_version,
    "org.springframework:spring-web:"+spring_version,
    "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:"+spring_version,
    "org.springframework:spring-orm:"+spring_version,
    "org.springframework:spring-asm:"+spring_version
] 

List spring_security = [
    "org.springframework.security:spring-security core:"+spring_sec_version,
    "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:"+spring_sec_version,
    "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:"+spring_sec_version
]

List spring_aop = [
    "aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0@jar",
    "cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2@jar"
]

List validation_lib = [
    "org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:4.3.0.Final@jar", 
    "javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA@jar"
]

List log_lib = [
    "org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.2.GA@jar", 
    "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.6@jar",
    "org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.6.6@jar",
    "org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:1.6.6@jar",
    "org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.6.6@jar",
    "log4j:log4j:1.2.17@jar"
]

List hibernate_api = [
    "org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final@jar"
] 

List hibernate = [
    "org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:1.0.1.Final@jar",
    "org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.1.Final@jar",
    "org.javassist:javassist:3.16.1-GA",
    "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:"+hibernate_version,
    "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:"+hibernate_version
]

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.10.19'
    compile hibernate_api
    compile hibernate
    compile spring 
    compile spring_security
    compile spring_aop
    compile "org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:1.9.9"  //lib jackson for JSON
    compile validation_lib
    compile log_lib
    runtime "postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901.jdbc4@jar"
    compile "rhino:js:1.7R2@jar"
}

task copyDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from (configurations.compile)
    into "src/main/resources"
}

task copyTestDependencies(type: Copy) {
    from (configurations.testCompile)
    into "src/test/resources"
}

build.dependsOn(copyDependencies)
build.dependsOn(copyTestDependencies)
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things before answering:

- The Gradle configurations `compile` and `testCompile` should be replaced with `implementation` and `testImplementation`. See [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/5.1.1/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_dependency_management_overview) for details. My answer will use these instead.
- Gradle has a great work avoidance approach, which is based on inputs / outputs computation. Copying anything into directories that are inputs of tasks, such as the `resources` directories, will mess that up. You really should avoid doing that and instead create new directories that are properly wired to be used where needed.

The problem you have is that `testImplementation` extends `implementation` and thus you will collect both *runtime* and *test* dependencies into the location for test dependencies.

- The easiest path is to create a custom configuration for your tests dependencies so that you can access them independently of the runtime ones:

  ```
  configurations {
      testDependencies
      testImplementations {
          extendsFrom testDependencies
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      testDependencies group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
      // And others
  }
  ```

  And then you would copy the contents of `testDependencies`.

  The one downside with this approach is that resolution of `testDependencies` will not be influenced by the *runtime* dependencies. This could be a problem but is context sensitive.
- The other option is to filter *runtime* dependencies when copying the *test* ones. That solution is required if you realise that runtime dependencies impact the version of test dependencies.